# Discord API integration in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, discord, discord.js

I'm developing an android app for a client, one of the requirements is that:
the application will have an input where the user will enter a text, and a button, when the user clicks on that button, the text in the input should be sent as a message to a specific discord server.

Any idea how I can achieve this either in react native or android studio, I spent a lot of time searching in the documentation and through the internet for a solution and I didn't find any useful information.

Comment: You can create an API that takes the input data and sends it to a Discord Bot which will then send it. However an answer to this question would be too vague

Comment: @Elitezen do you have an idea about how to create that API ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58903571/11884052